# Jsoup - how to extract all elements between a fixed html tag

Tags: jsoup

I need to extract text from this html markup between two strong html markup element

```
<h6>Main Heading</h6>
<ul>
<strong>Sub heading 1</strong>
<li>text1</li>
…
<li>textn</li>
<strong>Sub heading 2</strong>
<li>text1</li>
…
<li>textn</li>
</ul>
```

as in I need to get all the strong and li elements (text) in an array of Elements. I have tried to get all the strong elements as such

```
Element ulElement = doc.select("h6:matchesOwn(Main Heading).first();
Elements subHeadings = ulElement.select("strong");
Elements subLIElements = ulElement.select("strong ~ li");
```

So I have all the sub headings in subHeadings variable and all the li elements in the subLIElements variable... But i need to relate these two as in subHeadings[0] maps to all the li elements before the strong element. I am thinking I would need to traverse the tree to get these li elements ? Is there any other way i can do this in select query ?

Answer (score 0):

> get all the strong and li elements (text) in an array of Elements

Do you need only the text of each element, an array of `Element` or an array of `Elements`?

**If text only:**

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
Elements elements = doc.select("strong, li");

for( Element e : elements )
{
    result.add(e.text());
}
```

**Result:** [Sub heading 1, text1, textn, Sub heading 2, text1, textn]

In this example `elements` is a list containig all Strong / Li `Element`'s in the order of occurrence:

```
<strong>Sub heading 1</strong>
<li>text1</li>
<li>textn</li>
<strong>Sub heading 2</strong>
<li>text1</li>
<li>textn</li>
```

Maybe you can use the index of each Element to sort unwanted things out.